# deadlock when using torch.multiprocessing

Tags: python, pytorch, multiprocessing

I try to run the code below:

```
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
import torch
from torch import nn
import numpy as np

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        
        self.vars = nn.ParameterList()
        
        print("Net init 0")
        weight = nn.Parameter(torch.nn.init.orthogonal_(torch.zeros([64, 64]), 1.4))
        print("Net init 1")
        bias = nn.Parameter(torch.nn.init.constant_(torch.zeros(64), 1.4))
        print("Net init 2")
        self.vars.extend([weight, bias])
        print("Net init 3")
        
def f():
    net = Net()   
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    agent = Net()
    processes = [mp.Process(target=f) for _ in range(2)]
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

It seems to have encountered a deadlock. The init of Net in subprocesses doesn’t continue to print “Net init 1” and the program is stuck:

```
# python3 test.py 
Net init 0
Net init 1
Net init 2
Net init 3
Net init 0
Net init 0
```

However, if I comment the 1st line in main:

```
# agent = Net()
```

It works fine:

```
# python3 test.py 
Net init 0
Net init 0
Net init 1
Net init 2
Net init 3
Net init 1
Net init 2
Net init 3
```

If I don't use `torch.nn.init.orthogonal_` in **init**, it can work, too.

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by `libgomp`. In addition to `orthogonal_`, `torch.zeros` can also generate similar bugs if the tensor is large enough. It seems that it works fine when using `torch.rand` even if the tensor is large.

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/21956#issuecomment-636284398